# Reload DIV by clicking button inside DIV

Tags: javascript, php

How can I reload #order when button is clicked?

I have a php file that includes another php:

index.php:

```
<div id="order">
<?php include('order.inc.php'); ?>
</div>
```

order.inc.php:

```
<div class="update_database" data-ref="1">Update</div>
<div class="update_database" data-ref="2">Update</div>
<script>
  $('.update_database').click(function(){
    var target_id = $(this).attr('data-ref');
    var dataString = 'update=' + target_id;
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'post.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
     var result = $.trim(data);
     if (result == 'success') {
       $('#order').load('order.inc.php'); <= this is where I am having problem with
     } else if (result == 'accept') {
       // do something else
     } else {
       console.log(data);
     }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have tried to include the script in index.php and didn't work.

EDITED:

Simplified and remove irrelevant code:

order.inc.php"

```
<div class="update_database" data-ref="1">Update</div>
<div class="update_database" data-ref="2">Update</div>
<script>
  $('.update_database').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
    $('#order').load('order.inc.php'); <= this is where I am having problem with   
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check what's the contents of `result`? An AJAX inside another AJAX is not a good idea.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're making an AJAX request *inside* another AJAX request... Why not just have a single AJAX request?

Comment: Yes. dataString post successfully and information got updated on database. But I have to reload page manually which I can't cause I need to keep the index page active for other reason

Comment: Sorry, I don't see an AJAX inside another AJAX. Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using objects ID):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button_id").change(function(){
    var data=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'data'+data;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your_php_file.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#content_destination_id").html(html);
      } 
    });
  });
});
```

Note you could use the button value to pass any information to your PHP file.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. They were div instead of button and I have near to a hundred of these buttons so using object IDs may not be helpful.

Comment: You can still use IDs for those DIVs... But if you prefer classes, just change the character # for . (dot)

Comment: To reload the div depending on the result. And I only need to reload if the return value == 'success' or it will do something else. So I can't simple load the result as html to the DIV